# Problem with Xcode 13.1, SwiftUI, Mapkit and geoJSON - Polygon overlay does not render onto the map

Tags: xcode, mapkit, geojson

I am trying to show a geoJSON polygon on my IOS map app.  I'm using Xcode 13.1, SwiftUI and following some tutorials have coded the map which works successfully.  I am now trying to use a geoJSON file generated at geojson.io to display a polygon on the map, but so far I have been unsuccessful.  I've added some print statements to the code and I can see the geoJSON seems to parse and be decoded fine, but the mapView.addOverlays call doesn't seem to be calling the mapView function (no print).
If someone wouldn't mind having a look at my code below and point me in the right direction or help me figure out what I'm missing, that would be amazing.  Many thanks, Berto.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    
    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureLocationServices()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //function to check or request access to the users location while using the app
    private func configureLocationServices() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        let status = CLLocationManager()
        
        if  status.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            
        }   else if status.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
                beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: locationManager)
            
        }
    }
    
    //function to set GPS accuracy and continually track location on map
    private func beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
    }
    
    //function to set the zoomed area of the map around the current location
    private func zoomToLatestLocation(with coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    
        let zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
        mapView.setRegion(zoomRegion, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        print("mapView renderer called")
        if overlay is MKPolygon {
            let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        
            return renderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
 
    //function to update users location
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("did get latest location")
        
        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else { return }
        
        if currentCoordinate == nil {
            zoomToLatestLocation(with: latestLocation.coordinate)
            print("calling GeoJSON parse function")
            mapView.addOverlays(self.parseGeoJSON())
        }
        
        currentCoordinate = latestLocation.coordinate
    }
    
    func parseGeoJSON() -> [MKOverlay] {
        print("started geoJSON parse")
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "london", withExtension: "json") else {
            fatalError("unable to get geoJSON")
        }
        print("loaded trail1 geoJSON")
        var geoJSON = [MKGeoJSONObject]()
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            geoJSON = try MKGeoJSONDecoder().decode(data)
            print("decoded geoJSON")
        } catch {
            fatalError("unable to decode geoJSON")
        }
        var overlays = [MKOverlay]()
        for item in geoJSON {
            if let feature = item as? MKGeoJSONFeature {
                for geo in feature.geometry {
                    if let polygon = geo as? MKPolygon {
                        overlays.append(polygon)
                        print("appended polygon")
                      
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        print("returning overlays polygon")
        return overlays

    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("the status changed")
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: manager)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

London.json file generated from geojson.io

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -0.2581787109375,
              51.415481636209535
            ],
            [
              -0.078277587890625,
              51.36920841344186
            ],
            [
              0.1153564453125,
              51.46427482966439
            ],
            [
              0.13458251953125,
              51.586456488215426
            ],
            [
              -0.078277587890625,
              51.64358968607138
            ],
            [
              -0.28701782226562494,
              51.613752957501
            ],
            [
              -0.336456298828125,
              51.50703296721856
            ],
            [
              -0.2581787109375,
              51.415481636209535
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented the `mapView` delegate's renderer method...
...but you have not declared that your `ViewController` is also a `MKMapViewDelegate`...
...so the renderer is not being called.

I would put `MKMapViewDelegate` in it's own extension, like this:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        print("mapView renderer called")
        if overlay is MKPolygon {
            let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        
            return renderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}
```

...and don't forget to set `mapView`'s delegate to be your `ViewController`.